# NoSuchElement No value present after executing mvn test

Tags: spring, maven, junit5

I'm starting to develop unit tests for my services with JUnit 5.

After running the test I'm getting these errors:

*Results :*

*Tests in error:*

```
WorkSiteRepositoryTest.TestDelete:198 ▒ EmptyResultDataAccess
                  No class com.xxx.WorkSiteEntity entity with id 5 exists!
WorkSiteRepositoryTest.TestFind:137 ▒ NoSuchElement No value present
WorkSiteRepositoryTest.TestUpdt:161 ▒ NoSuchElement No value present
```

**Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0**

Entity:

```
// Company name.
@Size (max = 3)
@Column (name="emp", nullable=false, length=4, unique=true)
private Integer companyId = null;

// Work site ID.
@Id
@GeneratedValue (strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column (name="codlug", nullable=false, insertable=false, unique=true, updatable=false)
private Long id = null;

// Full name.
@Size (max = 40)
@Column (name="nombre", nullable=false, length=40)
private String  fullName = null;

// Short name.
@Size (max = 15)
@Column (name="nomabre", nullable=false, length=15)
private String  shortName = null;

// Country code.
@Size (max = 3)
@Column (name="pais", nullable=true, length=3)
private String  countryCode = null;

// Province code.
@Size (max = 3)
@Column (name="pcia", nullable=true, length=3)
private String  provinceCode = null;

// Province zip code.
@Size (max = 8)
@Column (name="codp", nullable=true, length=8)
private String  zipCode = null;

// Work site address.
@Size (max = 40)
@Column (name="direc", nullable=false, length=40)
private String  address = null;

// Building site number.
@Size (max = 9)
@Column (name="nroobra", nullable=true, length=9)
private Integer buildingNumber = null;

// Site's title
@Size (max = 4)
@Column (name="titlug", nullable=true, length=4)
private Integer siteTitle = null;

// Status
@Size (max = 1)
@Column (name="status", nullable=true, length=1)
private Integer status = null;

// Active
@Size (max = 4)
@Column (name="activ", nullable=true, length=4)
private Integer active = null;

// Is done
@Size (max = 1)
@Column (name="realiz", nullable=true, length=1)
private Integer done = null;

// Exoneration
@Size (max = 3)
@Column (name="exoneracion", nullable=true, length=3)
private Integer exoneration = null;

// Address number
@Size (max = 6)
@Column (name="domnro", nullable=true, length=2)
private Integer addressNumber = null;

// Office number
@Size (max = 6)
@Column (name="domofi", nullable=true, length=4)
private String  officeNumber = null;

// Phone number (1)
@Size (max = 25)
@Column (name="tel1", nullable=true, length=25)
private String  phoneNumber = null;

// Fax number
@Size (max = 25)
@Column (name="fax", nullable=true, length=25)
private String  fax = null;
```

Unit test
code used:

```
@Autowired
private IWorkSiteRepository workSiteRepository;

public WorkSiteRepositoryTest() {
    super ();
}

@BeforeEach
public void setup() {

    List<WorkSiteEntity> workSite = Arrays.asList (

            new WorkSiteEntity (1,
                    "testname", "aa", "aa", "aa", "1100",
                    "testaddress", null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
                    "9", "2342", "326"),
            new WorkSiteEntity (2,
                    "testname", "aa", "aa", "aa", "1200",
                    "testaddress", null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
                    "9", "623", "436"),
            new WorkSiteEntity (3,
                    "testname", "aa", "aa", "aa", "1300",
                    "testaddress", null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
                    "9", "342", "567"),
            new WorkSiteEntity (4,
                    "testname", "aa", "aa", "aa", "1400",
                    "testaddress", null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
                    "9", "543", "8567"),
            new WorkSiteEntity (5,
                    "testname", "aa", "aa", "aa", "1900",
                    "testaddress", null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
                    "9", "7754", "885")
    );

    this.workSiteRepository.saveAll(workSite);
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void release() {

    this.workSiteRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName ("Find a WorkSite Entity By Id.")
   public void TestFind () {

   WorkSiteEntity workSite;
   Long id = Long.valueOf(1500); // PK to search.

   workSite = this.workSiteRepository.findById(id).get(); // This is line 137

   assertNotNull(workSite, "[FINDBY] WorkSite " + id + " not found!");
   }

  @Test
  @DisplayName ("Update a WorkSite Entity By Id.")
  public void TestUpdt () {

  WorkSiteEntity workSite;
  Long id = Long.valueOf(1777); // PK to search.

  workSite = this.workSiteRepository.findById(id).get();

  assertNotNull (workSite, "[UPDATE] WorkSite " + id + " not found!");

  String before = workSite.getFullName ();
  workSite.setFullName (before.toUpperCase());
  this.workSiteRepository.saveAndFlush(workSite);

  workSite = this.workSiteRepository.findById(id).get(); // This is line 161

  assertNotNull (workSite, "[UPDATE] WorkSite not " + id + " found!");
  assertEquals (before.toUpperCase (), workSite.getFullName (), "[UPDATE] Update process failed!");
  }

   @Test
   @DisplayName ("Delete a WorkSite Entity By Id.")
   public void TestDelete () {

   WorkSiteEntity workSite;
   Long id = Long.valueOf(5); // PK to search.

   this.workSiteRepository.deleteById(id); // This is line 198

   workSite = this.workSiteRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
   assertNull (workSite, "[DELETE] WorkSite " + id + " found!");
   }

   @Test
   @DisplayName ("Find all WorkSites")
   public void TestFindAll () {

   List<WorkSiteEntity> workSite;

   workSite = this.workSiteRepository.findAll();

   assertNotNull (workSite, "[FINDALL] WorkSite not found (NULL)!");
   assertFalse (workSite.isEmpty (), "[FINDALL] WorkSite not found (Empty)!");
   }
```

Why I'm getting No value present error?
Also the error shows that there's no ID 5 but I added that ID to the object

I've commented the lines where the errors are shown

Comment: share/format the logs and also share the entity class to help.

Comment: I've added the entity, can't include the constructor and getters/setters due to code limitations but it shouldn't be needed

Comment: your tables are not created and entities are not saved thats the issue. Pls share what DB are you using to save the entities. check the logs whether DDL statements are executed for insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue:** is with primary field definition. Although you are deleting all the records in `@AfterEach` method, identity is going to keep increasing for each test, so first test will start from seq from 1..5, second test goes from 6..10 & goes on thats why it doesn`t find the entity by id.

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name="codlug", nullable=false, insertable=false, unique=true, updatable=false)
    private Long id = null;
```

**Reference** :

[stackoverflow-issue](https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/stackoverflow-issues/tree/master/issue-54423292-junit5-springboot-jpa)

**Result**:

[image]

**Note**: Below methods are not gonna work as primary value doesnt going to match.

```
   @Test
   @DisplayName ("Find a WorkSite Entity By Id.")
   public void TestFind () {

     Long id = Long.valueOf(1500); // PK to search.

   }

  @Test
  @DisplayName ("Update a WorkSite Entity By Id.")
  public void TestUpdt () {

    Long id = Long.valueOf(1777); // PK to search.
 }
```

use **Optional** to check whether element is present or not.

Comment: Still not working, I've changed the id's and got rid of the find by id test's error. Forgot to mention that I'm using H2 for the base

Comment: Did you try with the reference given ? Whats the issue now? For delete method id should be between 11 - 15. If you are not sure do find all and print the records to find out what's getting saved before you find